# Wireless xbox360-like pad

Tags: wireless, usb, gamepad, xbox-360

Can you please suggest a good wireless xbox-360 compatible pad (rechargeable via USB) which would work out of the box with Ubuntu 14.04+ and steam?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular X-input controller I can find is this [razer sabertooth](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Razer%20Sabertooth&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=YyMcVfuUEMug8wfBsIDwDQ).

It is the most used and praised 3rd party PC controller I can find but is expensive (60 usd+).

However ANY xbox 360 or xbox one 3rd party controller will work fine but bare in mind that you need the official wifi adapter from microsoft for most of these as xbox's don't have bluetooth.

Also ANY Playstation 3rd party pad will work with some tinkering but the results can vary.

It would be best to get one with its own receiver bundled in, as compatibility is an issue, and if you want steam game compatibility AVOID direct input, and buy X-input, it can work but is outdated.

The big issue with the 3rd party PC game pads is they are often very chatty with shit buttons and latency issues, I very much recommend not buying any cheap PC game pads EVER as they suck, like this one - [LogitechF710](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Logitech%20F710&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=OiMcVaPvFsug8wfBsIDwDQ)

EDIT: Heres some others I found [HERE](http://trust.com/en/all-products/18524-gxt-39-wireless-gamepad-for-pc--ps3?from=%7BD48D626F-74DD-4EF9-AD70-1A27EA141A4F%7D#Device:GAMING%20from:%7BD48D626F-74DD-4EF9-AD70-1A27EA141A4F%7D%5E12) and [HERE](http://trust.com/en/all-products/20340-gxt-530-dual-stick-gamepad?from=%7BD48D626F-74DD-4EF9-AD70-1A27EA141A4F%7D#Device:GAMING%20from:%7BD48D626F-74DD-4EF9-AD70-1A27EA141A4F%7D%5E13), they look good but are PS3 branded so no X-input, and you will find a few [HERE](http://www.thrustmaster.com/products/categories/gamepads-0) too.

No X-input is not the end of the world though, install `xboxdrv` to make it act like xinput

```
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
```

As a side note a X1 pad will now work with steam and they are hands down the best option.

Comment: Is what you're suggesting wireless and without batteries (USD chargeable)?

Comment: It seems not to have a wireless version, I am editing the answer to include others I found.

Comment: Here is the problem with PC gamepads, they only seem to come in two types cheap and crap that no one wants or professional like the Razor one, but NONE of the high end pads are wireless due to there "professional" nature. I feel for you, I would love a nice 3rd party PC pad but they are a pain to find.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a PS3 like (which actually I'm already using) but that I can use wireless... Using the pad itself over keyboard+mouse is already an expression of being a bit lazy :)

Answer (score 2):

The wireless Xbox360 controller works in Linux, you just have to get the `Xbox360 Wireless Receiver` adapter (sold separately or bundle with the controller, depending on which version you pick). For USB recharging you also need the Play&Charge kit, which is sold separately, normally the controller just runs on AA batteries and can't be charged with a regular cable. Also note that Play&Charge cable is for recharging only, it doesn't transmit input data to the PC, the Wireless Receiver is always required for the wireless controller.

XboxOne controller doesn't yet support wireless communication, but that might come in the future. It can be used with a regular USB cable, but I haven't tested that myself.

PS4 controller might also be worth a look, but I don't have any personal experience with that one either.

Comment: What about other brands? As I mentioned I would want to have a wireless with USB chargeable option (similar to PS3/4).